# How to capture image of any layout in background

Tags: android

I want to send graphs in email. So for that I have captured bitmap of that graph and save it in sdcard as image. that works successfully

```
private Bitmap TakeImage(View v) {
Bitmap screen = null;
 try {
     v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

     v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
          MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
     v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());

     v.buildDrawingCache(true);
     screen = v.getDrawingCache();
     v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
} catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
return screen;
}
```

But now I want to capture that in background without showing that layout, without notify by user. My previous code does not work for that.

Answer (score 1):

Inflate the view using `LayoutInflater`, populate the values and pass it on to the same `takeImage(View v)` method.

I'm not sure, and I've not tried, don't know whether this works or not. but give it a try.

Comment: How can this possible ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942641/convert-android-activity-layout-to-any-image-format?noredirect=1#comment24528337_16942641

OR take the capture image as big size ?? like 1200 * 800

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing `v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight()` to whatever values you desire?

Answer (score 0):

can you use

```
view.getLocationOnScreen(l);
```