# convert Android activity layout to any image format

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-listview

Am using Linear layout with is more then the mobile screen size. with visibility is hidden
that layout have some content inside. I need to take export that complete activity as image format  see the reference image i attached[image]

How to get the complete activity as image (jpeg or any other)

I tried with this code  but i can not able to get the full width image. i got only up to the mobile screen

Please correct it

```
View  layoutview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_outer);
        layoutview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bimg = layoutview.getDrawingCache();             

        File imgPath = new File("/sdcard/sample.png");
        FileOutputStream fOs = null;
        try {
            fOs = new FileOutputStream(imgPath);
            bimg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOs);
            fOs.flush();
            fOs.close();
            btndsbExport.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


    enter code here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Comment: Maybe try creating a new bitmap, a new canvas and pass in the bitmap to the constructor. Then call your views.draw method with the new canvas as the parameter. Haven't tried this yet though so have only put as comment :)

Comment: What do you mean by a full width image? Is your image width doesn't match with your device width?

Comment: I mean my device with is 240 * 800   but the linear layout width is 1200 * 800   this layout have background image or any grid view to place the images or any . if use that above code i can see the image up to my mobile screen width only.. remaining  from the image is cutted ... I hope now you clear what i mean

Comment: Try layoutview.setPersistentDrawingCache(ViewGroup.PERSISTENT_ALL_CACHES) and see if it helps. I guess setDrawingCacheEnabled(true) caches only the visible section. You can also try with PERSISTENT_SCROLLING_CACHE.

Comment: But For the layout i dont have any scrolling simply background rendering  and hide the visibility from the screen..

Comment: Not working any other way to handle.. that